# Failed to cast from an interface to a concrete implementation in MassTransit's event consumer

Tags: masstransit

I struggle to understand why i can't cast an interface that came in the message to a concrete implementation of it. The worst thing is that it worked before. but i'm unable to backtrack to the change that broke it. Maybe someone could give me a clue what's wrong.

We have a service XXX that shares contracts with other services, XXX.Contracts:

```
public interface IStuffUpdated : IEvent
{
    InvalidationReason Reason { get; }
    IStuffDto AffectedStuff { get; }
}
```

IStuffDto is something like this:

```
 public interface IStuffDto
 {
        Guid Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        ICollection<ISubStuffDto> SubStuff { get; set; }
 }
```

We have also another project in this solution, XXX.Shared:

```
public class StuffDto : IStuffDto
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ISubStuffDto> PlentySubStuff { get; set; } = new List<ISubStuffDto>();
}
```

Now we have another service that is an event consumer to the above, this service has imported XXX.Shared project:

```
    public class StuffUpdatedConsumer : IConsumer<IStuffUpdated>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IStuffUpdated> context)
        {

            var castedStuff = context.Message.AffectedStuff as StuffDto;

        }
    }
```

Up until recently the casting above worked just fine. Now i'm forced to use a mapper to get the same result which i'd like to avoid. What could be the breaking change for this?

Comment: When you consume an interface, MassTransit creates a proxy for that interface. Therefore, you can't cast it to an instance of the class, because it isn't an instance of the class. You could use `context.TryGetMessage<StuffDto>(out var stuffDtoContext)` and that should work though.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson thanks for your feedback. the thing is, casting worked (we have more consumers where such casting still works, but on less complex objects, no subcollections with other interfaces, if it makes any difference). i've managed to trackdown the the last release where it was still working. And then the commit that broke it. Changes in the commit were nowhere near close either event consumer or any interfaces/classes used in this flow. So, no idea why it stopped working. The trick with TryGetMessage didn't work, but i've figured out a different approach that is acceptable.

Comment: @skyrunner can you share with us your different approach please?

Comment: @Ozkan sorry, i don't really remember at this point but i remember i didn't figure out how to pass interfaces through masstransit. i probably restructured classes in the masstransit message to avoid interfaces.